# QRegexp and percent (%) sign

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp

I'm trying to match string of the form %foo% in a template. Context: The Goal is to replace %foo% by the value of the column foo in a stored procedure return.

I can't make it work. a the Beginning I tought the UTF8 encoding of my templates were the roots of my troubles. But even the below does fail:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QRegExp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString str = "__%foo%____";


    std::cout << "with regex: %(.*)%" << std::endl;
    QRegExp re("%(.*)%",Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    re.indexIn(str);
    for(int pos = 0; pos < re.captureCount(); ++pos)
    {
        std::cout << re.cap(pos).toStdString() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "with regex: \\%(.*)\\%" << std::endl;
    QRegExp re2("\\%(.*)\\%",Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    re2.indexIn(str);
    for(int pos = 0; pos < re2.captureCount(); ++pos)
    {
        std::cout << re2.cap(pos).toStdString() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "with regex: %([^%])%" << std::endl;
    QRegExp re3("%([^%])%",Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    re3.indexIn(str);
    for(int pos = 0; pos < re3.captureCount(); ++pos)
    {
        std::cout << re3.cap(pos).toStdString() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "with regex:  \\%([^\\%])\\%" << std::endl;
    QRegExp re4("\\%([^\\%])\\%",Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    re4.indexIn(str);
    for(int pos = 0; pos < re4.captureCount(); ++pos)
    {
        std::cout << re4.cap(pos).toStdString() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "with regex: \\x25([^\\x25])\\x25" << std::endl;
    QRegExp re5("\\x25([^\\x25])\\x25",Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    re5.indexIn(str);
    for(int pos = 0; pos < re5.captureCount(); ++pos)
    {
        std::cout << re5.cap(pos).toStdString() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "with regex: \\%(.*)\\%" << std::endl;
    QRegExp re6("\\%(.*)\\%",Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    re6.indexIn(str);
    for(int pos = 0; pos < re6.captureCount(); ++pos)
    {
        std::cout << re6.cap(pos).toStdString() << std::endl;
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
with regex: %(.*)%
%foo%
with regex: \%(.*)\%
%foo%
with regex: %([^%])%

with regex:  \%([^\%])\%

with regex: \x25([^\x25])\x25

with regex: \%(.*)\%
%foo%
```

I only want to capture foo, not the '%'

Comment: Remove the answer from your question and put it properly below in the answers section.

Comment: Well last time people asked me to do the opposite :D 
But fine I'm gonna keep both.

Comment: nonesense. An answer is not a question, therefore a question should not contain an answer. BTW, after some time you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Well for most questions, answer is gathered from different answers and put together at the top in a question edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok puting each and every

```
int pos = 0; pos < re.captureCount(); ++pos
```

as

```
int pos = 0; pos <= re.captureCount(); ++pos
```

I have the output:

```
with regex: %(.*)%
%foo%
foo
with regex: \%(.*)\%
%foo%
foo
with regex: %([^%])%


with regex:  \%([^\%])\%


with regex: \x25([^\x25])\x25


with regex: \%(.*)\%
%foo%
foo
```

The cap(0) matches the whole expression apparently

Answer (score 0):

Use non capturing groups:

```
QString txt="____%foo%___some%__";
QRegExp rx("(?:%)[^%]*(?:%)");
pos = rx.indexIn(txt, 0);
rx.capturedTexts().at(1); //holds foo
```

If you need all matches, loop with indexIn and provide pos+rx.matchedLenght() instead of 0